# publishing a web app consisting of an asp.net core project and an asp.net framework project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, ms-yarp

To tell the full story, I'm currently working on upgrading an asp.net mvc application, made using .net framework 4.8. We're looking into starting to use blazor, but this'll only work using a .net core web app. I'm using the .NET Upgrade Assistant to create a new asp.net core project, using YARP to route to all existing controllers, which all seems to work fine. What I can't figure out is how to publish these projects to our current webhosting platform. Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Why do think it has to be fundamentally different from the way you deployed before?

Comment: Fixed your "yarp" tag,  btw. There is a name clash with a c++ lib, so the reverse proxy goes by "ms-yarp", which I suppose you actually meant?

Comment: The approach is to first deploy the two separately while all traffic goes to the ASP.NET Core one, and then modify your YARP rules to forward part of the traffic from the ASP.NET Core web app to the .NET Framework one. There are just too many tiny steps and varied according to your hosting platform. Hope you can figure out on your own.

Comment: @Fildor, I'm not entirely sure, I just assumed it would be different because the hosting platform seems to simply throw everything from a publish operation together in a single folder.

Comment: @LexLi, thanks for summizing the general idea. I'll be sure to get in touch with people from the hosting platform!